# Magento 1.13.1.0 with Mysql 5.6.41

Tags: database, ee-1.13

I would like to know if Magento EE 1.13.1 works with MYSQL 5.6.41.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you please leave some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. **Magento ver. 1.13.1.0 EE** works with MySQL 5.6.

See this for more information: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html

Comment: I'm not sure about this link ... at to right you'll see `Magento Commerce, 1.14.x `. Unfortunately i did not found an older revision of this page.

Comment: Ahhh, you are correct. Hymmm, I can't find anything for 1.13.x. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_req-prereq_ubuntu.html

> Magento CE and EE support the following MySQL versions:
>
> - Magento CE 1.9.1 and Magento EE 1.14.1 support MySQL versions 5.0.2 through 5.6.x.
>     To install MySQL 5.6, see Installing MySQL 5.6.
> - Magento CE versions 1.8.0.0–1.9.0.x support MySQL versions 4.1.20–5.5.x.
>     To install MySQL version 5.5, see the next section.

MySQL 5.6 support was added in 1.9.1.0 for CE and i guess with 1.14 EE. I am not aware of any patch for 1.13.